# Creating a react component for gatsby-image (and passing in props of filenames and sizes)

Tags: gatsby

I'm new to working with gatsby-image.

I've got the example sample site up from gatsby/examples/using-gatsby-image/src/pages/ and it works locally using gatsby develop.

There are two next steps:

1. Hive off Img (and graphql queries) to another component and call that component from within blur-up.js - why? Because Img and graphql is verbose and doesn't match my current use of styled-components (it's inline)... and it allows the next step to take place (step 2).
2. Once it's running as a component then the parent can pass some simple props to it (filename, size). This then means anytime you want a blur-up image you could put this in the parent.

<
    ImageInsert fsfile="michae" maxwidth="800"  />

and let the component handle the graphql calls using (in this case michae as the regex for the imagefilename).

#### My problem is I can't even get step one going.

Here's what I do

### REMOVE gatsby-image references from the parent file (blur-up.js) and ADD an import to a component that has the gatsby-image (./imageinsert)

```
import React from "react"
import ImageInsert from "./imageinsert"
import { rhythm, options } from "../utils/typography"

const BlurUp = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Viribus quid</h1>
    <h2>Hippason sinu</h2>


    <p>
      Lorem markdownum nocens, est aut tergo, inmansuetique bella. Neve illud
      contrarius ad es prior.{` `}
      <a href="http://nunc.io/fuit.html">Planguntur</a> quondam, sua ferunt
      uterum semina advertere si fraudesque terram hosti subiecta, nec. Audenti
      refugitque manibusque aliis infelicem sed mihi aevis! Que ipso templa; tua
      triformis animumque ad coluit in aliquid.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>Infamia lumina sequuntur ulla</li>
      <li>Aquarum rutilos</li>
      <li>Hinc vimque</li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Et solebat pectus fletus erat furit officium</h2>
    <p>
      Proteus ut dis nec exsecrantia data: agrestes, truculenta Peleus. Et
      diffidunt, talia intravit Thaumantias; figere et <em>et</em> qui socio
      qui, <a href="http://vixmonet.io/in.html">tuo servet unda</a> hoc{` `}
      <strong>classi</strong>? Causam <em>quemque</em>? Subigebant cornibus
      fibras ut per nare nati, cunctis et <strong>illa verba</strong> inrita.
    </p>
    <ol>
      <li>Furori adacto</li>
      <li>Nocent imagine precari id ante sic</li>
      <li>Ipsos sine Iuno placabitis silet relinquent blandarum</li>
      <li>Et pars tabe sociorum et luna illum</li>
      <li>Et frustra pestifero et inquit cornua victa</li>
      <li>Constitit nomine senta suspirat et signis genuisse</li>
    </ol>

    <h2>Levia mihi</h2>
    <p>
      Precor Ortygiam, prudens diro stabant prodis moenia; aut tergo{` `}
      <a href="http://orehaec.io/">loquax et data</a> sua rite in vulnere. Esse
      lumina plaustrum lacus necopina, iam umbrae nec clipeo sentit{` `}
      <a href="http://ut.org/hinc">sinistra</a>.
    </p>
    <ImageInsert/>
    <p>
      Pendebat nitidum vidistis ecce crematisregia fera et lucemque crines.{` `}
      <a href="http://www.sub.net/">Est sopita satis</a> quod harena
      Antimachumque tulit fusile. Fieri qui que prosit equidem, meis praescia
      monebat cacumina tergo acerbo saepe nullaque.
    </p>
  </div>
)

export default BlurUp
```

### NOW ADDING imageinsert.js I start with something simple (just add a h1 line)

and it works:

```
import React from "react"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

export default ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello gatsby-image</h1>
  </div>
)
```

my browser shows this inserted:

## Hello gatsby-image

[so far, so good, the component is inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adEXz.png)

So all I need to do now is enable the gatsby-image tag (Img) and graphql query. I try various options (see uncommented and commented below). But when I do this I get a blank page (browser) and console errors suggesting a null:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined
    at new _default (imageinsert.js:7)
```

Here's some variations I tried:

```
import React from "react"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

export default ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello gatsby-image</h1>
    <Img resolutions={data.file.childImageSharp.resolutions} />
  </div>
)

// export const query = graphql`
//     query ImageInsertQuery {
//       imageSharp(id: { regex: "/nasa/" }) {
//       sizes(maxWidth: 1500) {
//         ...GatsbyImageSharpSizes
//       }
//     }
//   }
// `


export const query = graphql`
  query GatsbyImageSampleQuery {
    file(relativePath: { eq: "images/nasa-45072.jpg"}) {
      childImageSharp {
        resolutions(width: 125, height: 125) {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpResolutions
        }
      }
    }
  }
`




// class ImageInsert extends React.Component {
//   render() {
//     return (
//       <div>
//         {/* <Img
//         title={`Photo of Michael`}
//           sizes={this.props.data.imageSharp.sizes}
//         /> */}
//         <h1>mg is here </h1>
//       </div>
//     )
//   }
// }
//
// export default ImageInsert
//
// export const query = graphql`
//     query ImageInsertQuery {
//       imageSharp(id: { regex: "/nasa/" }) {
//       sizes(maxWidth: 1500) {
//         ...GatsbyImageSharpSizes
//       }
//     }
//   }
// `
//


// const ImageInsert = ({ data }) => (
//   <div>
//     <h1>yayness {data.mgImage.sizes}</h1>
//     {/* <Img
//       sizes={data.mgImage.sizes}
//       title={`Photo of Michael`}
//     /> */}
//   </div>
// )
//
// export default ImageInsert
//
```

None work for me. Anytime I put in the Img I get a blank page.  Unfortunately I haven't got access to any other examples. The examples from https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/ have a typo @ - an (L) instead of (1) for the width (it's l25 instead of 125) so I am not sure if anyone has examples of what i am trying to do? Or advice on how to get this into another component.

```
file(relativePath: { eq: "images/an-image.jpeg"}) {
      childImageSharp {
        resolutions(width: l25, height: 125) {
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

In Gatsby you can pull data **only** into "page" or "layout" components.

Gatsby converts all your data to static and pre-fetches data. So it must know exactly what data is required on each page.

Comment: But is there really no way to include an image with `gatsby-image` without using 5-6-7 lines for every image you want to use? That is rather a huge load of boiler plate. There should be a way to statically define it and get a nice API like that suggested, a one-liner for importing different images (with same settings).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do something like this: use a component to load *ALL* the images that exist, then filter based on the data you got back to only supply the image you want.

All images will need the same settings then, and they'll all be rendered to that setting. But this can be okay for some use cases. Very interesting.

There's a code example in another StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56508865/179978